# How to prevent property changes after it is assigned in the constructor?

Tags: c#, properties

```
class Student
{
    private int Id { get; set; }

    public Student(int current_Id)
    {
        this.Id = current_Id;
    }
}
```

How can I prevent changes to the property Id after it is assigned in the constructor of my class. If I use `const` for `Id` I get an error.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you asking how to make Id not change after `Student` is created? Or are you asking why can you not change the Id after a student is created?

Comment: Yes I'm asking how to make Id not change after Student is created.

Comment: use `public readonly`, or `public get/private set`

Answer (score 1):

Mark `Id` as readonly:

```
public readonly int ID;
```

A `readonly` property can only be changed in the class' constructor. [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/readonly)

Also, you seem to be confused about `current_Id`. If you want to make every student have a different id, make `current_Id` a private static field in the class, not a constructor parameter.

```
private static int current_Id = 0;
```

The reason why `const` does not work is that things marked with `const` must have a constant value at compile time. Obviously, a student ID is not such a value.

Comment: @Sweeper That use-case is quite common when you have to deserialize an object with a PK ID. Once the object is constructed that, that ID is PERMANENT and we wouldn't want something accidentally changing/removing it. On the other hand, if its a "NEW" instance, the constructor would generate the ID or retrieve a new one from another source-of-truth. That gets serialized later and when it comes back, we're back to this use-case.

Answer (score 0):

You have private **auto properties**. You can't change any of these values after creation of the instance from scope where the instance is created. The only way to change them is to change from the Class's scope. If you want to not allow change of them at all(allow only from construtor) you can do it in the following way

```
private int Id { get; }
```

Or you can use property with **readonly** field as is written in @Sweeper's answer.